# jQuery dropdown if selected value

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```
$('[name^=business_] option:selected').each(function(){
    var bus = $(this).text();
    alert(bus);
});
```

This brings back the selected values of all the dropdowns with the name beginning with `business_` - this is fine.

What I need is, if `none` of the dropdowns have a selected value equal to or higher than 1 then return an alert.

But I cannot fathom how to achieve this, I've tried looking at adding the values together but no joy - any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the dropdowns, and once you find one with a value greater than one, set a flag and break the loop.

```
var foundOne = false;
$('[name^=business_] option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() >= 1) {
        foundOne = true;
        return false;
    }
});

if (!foundOne) {
    alert('No selected options had a value of 1 or higher'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not quite there - what I need is if all `10` dropdowns are not equal to or greater than 1 then an alert needs to happen - not at each iteration.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you may be confused on the `return false;`. That is returning from the anonymous function within `each()`. It doesn't return from whatever validation function this is all contained in. You can `return false;` from `each()` to break the loop and stop iterating.

Comment: THANK YOU for the update - a stonking piece of code that works perfectly.  That has had me stumped for hours!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) then check the `length`:

```
   var arr = $('select option:selected').filter(function(){
       if(this.value > 1)
           return this; 
    });

    if(arr.length) // arr.length > 0 also valid
        alert('yes');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/vaTVX/1/

Comment: Because we only need one item to meet the criteria. `filter()` will iterate the entire list even when the first item meets the success condition.